# Bash dictionary attack - prints whole dictionary rather than runs process

Tags: bash, security, unix, dictionary, scripting

My bash dictionary attack function will select the first word from the dictionary and see if it compares with my hash but then stop, and if it doesn't, it will search the whole dictionary but not actually return the password. When it stops the password is always "1080", no matter what the hash is

I don't understand what's happening, but I've researched quite a lot

```
dict_attack(){
TARGET_HASH=$1
while read WORD; do
    WORD_HASH=$(echo $WORD | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ "$WORD_HASH"=="$TARGET_HASH" ]; then
            echo "Guessed it!"
            echo "Password is : $WORD"
            exit
    fi
done < /usr/share/dict/linux.words
```

Here is the call in the rest of the script.

```
dict_attack $1
```

Comment: `"$WORD_HASH"=="$TARGET_HASH"` Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You also don't want to `exit` from your function.  You are looking for `return`.

Comment: Also, don't use uppercase for your private variables; uppercase is reserved for system variable names.

Answer (score 0):

`if [ "$WORD_HASH"=="$TARGET_HASH" ]` does not do what you expect.  It always evaluates to true, since the string `"$WORD_HASH"=="$TARGET_HASH"` is always non-empty.  Add some whitespace around the `==` operator and write it:

```
if [ "$WORD_HASH" == "$TARGET_HASH" ]
```

Comment: I'm trying this, and it's looking up! I'll update you. You are a legend if it fixes it

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces around `==` (or `=`) in `[` (`test`) command (and also in `[[` keyword):

```
if [ "$WORD_HASH" == "$TARGET_HASH" ]
```

Otherwise you are just doing the `-n` test i.e. check if the string is non-zero which will always be true as you have `==`:

```
if [ -n "$WORD_HASH"=="$TARGET_HASH" ]
```